# Which sentence is correct? Guess Questions

Tags: grammar

Which sentence is correct?

1) Guess what does it mean.
2) Guess what it means does.

Answer (score 1):

While neither sentence is grammatical as written, what's interesting is that the exact same words *could* form grammatical sentences if certain punctuation were added.

> Guess. What does it mean?
>   Guess what? It means *does*.

Answer (score 0):

Neither is correct. It should be: `Guess what it means.` (Or I guess, `Guess what it does mean` is also grammatical but the `does` makes it sound overly formal and somewhat awkward. EDIT: as FumbleFingers pointed out, this latter sentence makes perfect sense in a context like this: `It does not mean X. Guess what it *does* mean` - where the `does` is emphasized while speaking.)

Comment: I'm not completely on board with *overly formal and somewhat awkward* there. Consider a context such as *Okay, you say you're sure it **doesn't** mean X, but that doesn't get us far. Guess what it **does** mean.* I'd say that's more likely to occur in "informal" contexts.

Comment: @FumbleFingers - thanks, you're right - in this context it is correct and neither awkward nor formal. I will edit my answer.

Comment: I do realise I'm "cheating" a bit by highlighting ***does*** in my example above, and your point is perfectly valid unless heavy stress is placed on the auxiliary verb. But it might be worth pointing out that although technically speaking, optional ***do*** in the first sentence of *this* comment does in fact provide "emphasis", it doesn't *require* such heavy stress (you can read it however you want, and / or I could have chosen to typographically highlight it! :)